# SSH version 7.2 is showing up as 7.1 in client

Tags: ssh

We upgraded our Ubuntu Linux 14.04.1 to the latest OpenSSH version 7.2p2.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-1-4-137:~$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

However, when I try to check the version from a client, it shows up as 7.1. Please see below:

```
ram@ip-10-1-14-44:~$ telnet 10.1.4.137 22
Trying 10.1.4.137...
Connected to 10.1.4.137.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1p1 Ubuntu-1~ubuntu14.04.1~ppa1
```

What could be causing this issue? Our security scanning software relies on the information provided by the server and this is being flagged as a vulnerability.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the startup script for sshd in /etc/init.d and compare the path of which sshd. Are those the same?

Comment: Have you restarted `sshd` since upgrading?